# Error shows up on gradle sync

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am new to android studio. When I import the project[1] and sync the gradle file, it tells me

> Error:No such property: sourceFiles for class:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

[1] https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android Studio are you using?

If the FoldableLayout project is the one you are trying to open, you will need to use a later version of the android gradle plugin if you are using the latest Android Studio.

In the gradle-wrapper.properties, change the distributionUrl to:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip
```

And in the library build.gradle, change the buildscript classpath to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```